# Line Break not saving in Database

Tags: javascript, database, vcf-vcard

I am working on VCard project in ASP.NET MVC.  I need to save VCard result in database with linebreak.

I am storing all results in one column called **cartText**. This is my code :

```
    QrString += "var compiled_card_data = \"BEGIN:VCARD\" + \"\\n\"\n" + "+";
   QrString += "\"VERSION:2.1\" + \"\\n\"\n" + "+";
   QrString += "\"FN:\" + firstname + \"\\n\"\n" + "+";
   QrString += "\"N:\" + lastname  + \"\\n\"\n" + "+";
   QrString += "\"END:VCARD\" + \"\\n\"\n";
```

When I debug, I can see results with line break in correct format.

I am storing this result in SQL Management Studio, for later retrieval. But in DB, results are storing without break. 
So when i try to scan, i can see all results in one line.

So how can i store results in DB with line break

Comment: SQL Management Studio wont show the line breaks, the will appear as a single line with an extra space. Would be best to use `Environment.NewLine` anyway

Comment: @musefan Hi i tried Envirnoment.NewLine. But it also saves results in one one line in DB.

Comment: by default **SQL Management Studio wont show the line breaks**, try exporting the data to see the breaks. or read the data from the database and back in to your application to see them

Comment: Hi, could you show how you are storing the result in the database?

Comment: Yes I did that. When i extract results into App, I can see all results in one line because results in DB are stored in one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
QrString += "\"BEGIN:VCARD\"" + "\n\r";
QrString += "\"VERSION:2.1\"" + "\n\r";
QrString += "\"FN:\"" + firstname + "\n\r";
QrString += "\"N:\"" + lastname  + "\n\r";
QrString += "\"END:VCARD\"" + "\n\r";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not already correct in the database?  You need to "show results as text" in SQL Management Studio in order to see the database results with line breaks.

Comment: Yes I did this. I am checking result as results to text and i cannot see proper format.